# Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped. Facebook

Tags: facebook

Good Morning,
I have problems with the way fb connects to my server.
I don't know why but Facebook can't reach any of the websites hosted in our server:
http://www.gicconsulting.net

http://www.ggdisseny.com

I'm trying the debug tool but it gives me the following error: "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."

Any idea about what can I do with it?
The websites were before hosted in another server and it was everything fine, FB were able to connect them, but since 3 days ago(when we moved server) it can't reach...

Thank you!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ggdisseny.com%2F works fine for me.

Comment: [IMG]http://i40.tinypic.com/o58hmw.jpg[/IMG] check the screenshot.

Comment: http://i40.tinypic.com/o58hmw.jpg